# I get a Gradle sync error when I try to create a new project on Android Studio 0.6.1

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

The error I get:

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

How do I change the SDK build tools version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go into your build.gradle file and change your Build to this:

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`

It should be located in your project folder (the one that contains src and build folders). If you can't find it in your build.gradle file, it's possible there's a second file that has this correct piece. Note, only change the `buildToolsVersion`, don't add anything else.

Comment: My build.gradle file only has the code given below, none of the ones you mentioned, can I just add it the file?



    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies     here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Comment: Ahh sorry, I update the location of the folder. There should be two build.gradle files, see if you can find both of them. One of them will have the code you need to change.